# How do I implicitly implement method in generic class, derived from abstract?

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

I am trying to have a List of classes that implement a generic class and be able to access some members of the GenericClass through the abstract base. This is where I am at the moment:

```
public abstract class AbstractParent: UserControl
{
    public abstract AAction Action { get; set; }
}

public abstract class GenericBase<ActionType> : AbstractParent 
{
    protected ActionType _action;

    new public ActionType Action
    {
        set { _action = value; }
        get { return _action; }
    }
}
```

In order to have a list of GenericBase<> instances, I use a `List<AbstractParent>`

The problem is that I want a public property of the genericType (passed by the derived class from GenericBase).

The error at the moment is `Action hides inherited abstract member Action.get`.
I know that I can either have an abstract proprty and an implementation, or implementation and `new` modifier in the derived property. Both don't fit in this situation.

example of what I want:

```
GenericBase<BlueAction> blueClass;
blueClass.Action <- I want this member to be of BlueAction type
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't; you'd need 2 levels of derived type to pull that off, I suspect (one for the `override`, one for the `new`)

Comment: Any workarounds @MarcGravell?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  WHY do you need it to do that.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @odyodyodys sure - rather than a public abstract method, have a public concrete method that **calls** a protected abstract method of a different name; then you can `new` the public method and `override` the abstract one, without any conflicts

Comment: @the downvoters: Mind to comment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface IActionable 
{
  public ActionType Action { get; }
}

public class ActionableWrapper : IActionable
{ 

  private ActionType _action;

  public ActionableWrapper(IActionable Actionable)
  {
    this._action = Actionable;
  }

  new public ActionType Action 
  { 
    get { return _action; } 
  } 
} 

public class BlueAction: IActionable
{
  public ActionType Action { get; }
}
```

This does what you want, granted not using generics.  Since I can't figure out WHY you'd want a `List<ActionableWrapper>` when instead of using generics you could just use an interfaces and make it simplely `List<IActionable>`.

`I am trying to have a List of classes that implement a generic class and be able to access some members of the GenericClass through the abstract base.`

Using Linq you can do this easily anyway (using your example):

```
List<AbstractParent> AbstractParentCollection = new List<AbstractParent>();
GenericBase<BlueAction> blueClass;     
AbstractParentCollection.Add(blueClass);
AbStractParentCollection.Typeof(GenericBase<BlueAction>).First().Action...
```

Answer (score 1):

Can your AbstractParent be redesigned to require ActionType:

```
public abstract class AbstractParent<ActionType>
{
    public abstract Action<ActionType> Action { get; set; }
}
```

then your inherited class can override, if needed:

```
public override Action<ActionType> Action
```

**Update**

An alternative is to have ActionType implement a new interface, such as IActionType. The return property from the base class would be the interface and this wouldn't necessarily need to be overridden in the inherited class.

Here is the complete class/interface structure:

```
public interface IAction
{
}

public abstract class AbstractParent
{
    public abstract IAction Action { get; set; }
}

public abstract class GenericBase<T> : AbstractParent where T : IAction
{
    protected IAction _action;

    public override IAction Action
    {
        get
        {
            return _action;
        }
        set
        {
            _action = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But then I cannot have a list of those object.
I was using `List<AbstractParent>` to hold `GenericBase` instances. I've made this in order to access `GenericBase`'s members

Comment: What about using an Interface for the value of Action instead of a class?

Comment: I had omitted that AbstractBase inherits from UserControl for clarity

Comment: Ok, but that wouldn't prevent you from changing `public abstract AAction Action { get; set; }` to `public abstract IAction Action { get; set; }` would it? Then you could have Action implement IAction.

Comment: Yes this can be done. I am missing something on your solutions. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @odyodyodys: Ok, I have updated the answer with the full approach.